# How to Update/Tag/Publish a module repo

Tags: yarnpkg

My notes show I used `yarn publish next` in the past, which i thought did the following

1. prompt for version
2. update package.json w/ version
3. create a commit/tag w/ version
4. publish the commit to the registry

Unfortunately this command signature doesn't exist in the docs, and from the following I think the command thinks I am trying to publish a tarball file named "next"

```
> yarn publish next
yarn publish v1.22.19
`error Passed folder/tarball doesn’t exist,`
```

What `yarn publish` command should I use instead? OR, can this only be accomplished with multiple steps?

Answer (score 0):

Call `yarn publish`

This will...

1. Prompt for the next version number
2. Update your `package.json` with the version you provide
3. Commit a tag locally
4. Publish the version in your registry

(You will still need to manually push the tagged commit to your repo and get it merged)

If you have already updated package.json with the new version number, just type that version number when prompted, it will update it with whatever version you provide to it.